# Angular 2 view not updated after API call

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular2-changedetection

I have a angular2 component, inside of which I have a method that populates data from API call by calling service method.

```
getData() {
  this.someBinding = "Initial value";
  this.someService.get('some url').then(() => {
    this.someBinding = "Updated Value";
   }
  ).catch(//error handling)
}
```

I call getData() method inside **ngOnInit()** lifecycle hook like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.getData();
}
```

Problem is, inside view {{someBinding}} is not updated after API call is finished. I get data properly in my API call, but binding not updated.

I found solution to manually fire change detection (**this.cdr.detectChanges()**) after data has arrived inside getData().then(), which is working just fine.

> I am not able to identify what the problem is in this case, why I need to fire change detection manually. I have not found the reason but solution just works fine. Please explain.

Comment: It depends on your service. How does it retrieve the data?

Comment: Service retrives data in form of promise (by converting observable to promise)

Comment: Are you using the `http` service from angular?

Comment: Yes, I am using Http class of angular, which returns me a observable, and I convert it to promise by calling **toPromise()** method.
I am getting data perfectly, but for binding to update, I am forced to run change detection manually, which I don't want to do. Bindings are not updated otherwise, I would like to know, why?

Comment: They should update. Or your component (or one of its parents) is using a different `ChangeDetectionStrategy`

Comment: No, its Default

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to convert an observable to a promise, you're better off using the observable directly.

service:

```
getData(): Observable<Something> {
  return this.http.get(...)
}
```

component:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.someBinding = this.service.getData();
}
```

component template:

```
{{ someBinding | async }}
```

Angular can render observables directly in the view using async. It will also automatically unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. It's best to stick with the Observable API as it is used throughout the Angular application

Comment: I have a whole large application in angular2, performing multiple Http calls, so I have written a wrapper that converts observable in promise. With promise, it should work right? Because I am not getting this problem anywhere else in my code.

Comment: Observables are far more powerful than promises and are better equipped to handle large applications with many http calls. To convert them all to promises is a huge step backwards and goes against the direction Angular - and for that matter all reactive and asynchronous - platforms are headed